# How in a maven project can I import classes coming from an external war which don't comes from a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, testing

I work for a company which has a Java project containing some code for their software.
I created a maven project to test some API on their software and make some automatic build on TeamCity.

To test those API response, I use some classes from their original Java project, which is not a Maven project.
When doing this on Eclipse, no problem if I configure well the build path. But, when trying to compile with Maven, I've got an error saying that package ...impl.api.v1.measures.beans does not exist.
The original Java project, when compilated, produce a war file.

How can I import those classes from the compilated war file, in my Maven project ?

Comment: Use the same build system as they do.

Comment: It's not common to use classes in one project from another WAR file. Java does not include any way to put a WAR on the class path and uses classes inside its `WEB-INF/classes` directory. A better idea is to package those classes in a JAR file that is used both from the web app project and the test project you're working on. The JAR could then be deployed to a Maven repository: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: Can the build for the WAR file be modified to produce BOTH a war and a jar